# Integrating AngularJS contact form in a bootstrap designed page - Navbar's dropdowns not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I created a contact form with angularJS and when I try to integrate it in the page that I built with bootstrap, the Navbar dropdowns and the toggle button don't work. How do I fix it in the best and easiest way?

[Link To My Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ljO3BL5grnTQvRntDZUy?p=preview)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="container">

        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span> Our Product<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">A Collaborative Solution </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">A Robust Platform</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>

                    </ul    

                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> About Us<b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Advisory Board</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Partners</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Customers</a></li>


                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> In the News<b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Press Releases</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Industry News</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact Us   </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your plunk is not including the bootstrap.js

Comment: Not sure how you will be using angular, but the easiest way to mix both bootstrap and angular is to use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @RobJ - It does now, but I don't think that that's the problem.

Comment: Your plunk is also missing the jQuery library, console is throwing an error. I cleaned up the references on this [fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/WdubWLb90eLupO5MXWNr?p=preview) and it seems to work.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Is there anything else you need to know about this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Bootstrap's js file and try to avoid jQuery with Angular (jQuery shouldn't be needed). Instead, just include **[`UI Bootstrap`](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown)** and it will add bootstrap's JavaScript functionality as Angular directives.

Include the `ui-bootstrap` script:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

then, inject it as a module dependency in your app:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.bootstrap'
]);
```

This will make the Bootstrap components work in your application. Be sure to read the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown) for UI Bootstrap.